# Changes made to the dll are not reflecting in the Application where I am using this dll

Tags: c#, windows-services, gac, windows

I have a Class library project. I am installing this dll produced by the project into the GAC by the command "gacutil /i [Path of the dll]". This dll is used by a windows application. When windows application runs, it successfully accesses the functions and properties of the dll.
    Now I have made some changes to the dll. I have uninstalled the original dll from the GAC and will install the newer dll with the required changes. Now when the windows application uses this dll, the new changes from the dll are not getting reflected in the application. The new changes should reflect into the application as I installed the new dll into the GAC.
    The Name, version and Public key token is the same for both dlls. I think it won't matter as the i have uninstalled the previous dll and installed the new dll into the GAC.

Am I doing something wrong?? Please suggest a solution.

Thanks and Regards,
Mayur Mahajan

Comment: What changes did you make? There are some changes I can imagine (such as the values of constants) which won't be seen without recompiling your app. Given that you've said it's a "windows application" I can't see why this is tagged asp.net.

Comment: Have you restarted the windows service? The changes will only reflect if you stop the windows app/service and start it again. It keeps dll in memory.

Comment: I think your suggestion could work..! I think it is keeping dll in memory. Can you please suggest me how to restart the Windows app/service. I don't want to restart this this programatically(taht means not through my app). So please suggest a manual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for debugging purposes that you version your dll, then print the version to your application to be sure its being updated.  Include the System.Reflection namespace and the code would run look like the following:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("unknown.dll");
label.Text = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, But I don't want to version my dll. I want some other way to solve this issue. Versioning dll is not a solution for this issue, because while developing if I am doing changes 1000 times, then I will have to make 1000 versions of it.
      I think this dll would have get stored into the memory. Can I have some way to solve this..?